# Export Failed Element Log(s) after deliver?

Tags: export, clearcase, element, logging

When a deliver has been performed I can rightlick an entry in the GUI version/element log and it displays me a popup with the element log. Quite handy.

I now have a delivery with about 25 failed ones and a couple of hundred OK's. Sadly I can not sort on the column "status" so I have to make screenshots wherever I find a [!] to sit together with the specific team to find out if it is really ok to not deliver those.

It would however be handy to have this list of element logs from a deliver so that I do not have to make screenshots or copy the contents of the popup box one by one but just have a list of the failed ones with the element log.

Is there a way to export the element logs from a deliver (so the the ones that show up when you rightclick and choose "Display Element Log") and/or only the ones that gave failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a deliver fails graphically, one possible solution is to resume it through the command line (`cleartool deliver -resume`), grepping for the "`cleartool Error`" message.

At least that way, you have a text information to share.
Other than tat, I do not know of a way to export the deliver result directly from the GUI.